# Calculating age/tenure in HiveQL

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql

I'm using the below code to calculate tenure/customer age using datediff

```
select user_id, datediff('2014-09-30', to_date(date_joined)) as tenure_days
from users_table 
group by user_id
```

Error

```
Error: Invalid column reference date_joined
```

Any help here would be highly appreciated!

Comment: date_joined should be String timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for grouping here. Try bellow:

```
select distinct user_id, datediff('2014-09-30', to_date(date_joined)) as tenure_days 
from users_table
```